# How do I store the resulting table from a SELECT query in a variable?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have the following query, which returns a filtered table:

```
select column1,column2,column3 from table1 where table1.column1 = 'dada'
```

Further, suppose I want to store the resulting values in a variable so that I can use the result later on.

I have read that I can store a single value like so:

```
declare:
   result varchar(20);
begin:
   select column1 into result from table1 where table1.column1 = 'dada';
end;
```

But what about multiple values? There doesn't seem to be a "TABLE" or "DICTIONARY" datatype.

Comment: I am expecting `into`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a **view** instead.

From W3Schools:

> In SQL, a view is a virtual table based on the result-set of an SQL
>   statement.

Here's how you create one:

```
create view view1 as select column1,column2,column3 from table1 where
table1.column1 = 'dada'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use collections in oracle. Below code can help you.

Sample Code:

```
    CREATE TABLE example
   ("S_ID" NUMBER(1,0) , 
    "S_NAME" VARCHAR2(8 CHAR)
   );

    Insert into example (S_ID,S_NAME) values (1,'A');
    Insert into example (S_ID,S_NAME) values (1,'B');
    Insert into example (S_ID,S_NAME) values (1,'C');
    Insert into example (S_ID,S_NAME) values (2,'A');
    Insert into example (S_ID,S_NAME) values (2,'B');
    Insert into example (S_ID,S_NAME) values (2,'C');
    Insert into example (S_ID,S_NAME) values (3,'A');
    Insert into example (S_ID,S_NAME) values (3,'B');

    commit;


    DECLARE
       TYPE type_name IS TABLE OF example%rowtype;
       var_type_name   type_name;
    BEGIN
         SELECT *
           BULK COLLECT INTO var_type_name
           FROM example;

           for r in var_type_name.first..var_type_name.last loop
              dbms_output.put_line(var_type_name(r).s_id||','||var_type_name(r).s_name);
           end loop;

    END;
```

Help link:
https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/working-with-collections

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20316106)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have added the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

```
create view tempTable as select column1,column2,... from table1 where
table1.column1 = 'dada'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare:
   result varchar(20);
begin:
   select column1 into result from table1 where table1.column1 = 'dada'; // only work if you have single column in your result
end;
```

// For Multiple values use implicit  cursor like below
FOR c_2151 in (
         select column1  from table1 where table1.column1 = 'dada'
      ) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Display: '|| c_2151.column1);
        END LOOP;

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.